# Pandas DataFrame: sort_values by an index with empty strings

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas `DataFrame` with multi level index. I want to sort by one of the index levels. It has float values, but occasionally few empty strings too which I want to be considered as `nan`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=[1,2,3,4]), index=[1,2,3,''])
df.index.name = 'i'
df.sort_values('i')
   TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

One way to solve the problem is to replace the empty strings with `nan`, do the sort, and then replace `nan` with empty strings again.

I am wondering if there is any way we could tweek the `sort_values` to consider empty stings as `nan`.

#### Why there are empty strings in the first place?

In my application, actually the data read has missing values which is read as `np.nan`. But, `np.nan` values cause problem with `groupby`. So, they are replace to empty strings. I wish we had a constant like `nan` which is treated like empty string by `groupby` and like `nan` for numeric operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering if there is any way we could tweek the sort_values to consider empty stings as nan.

In pandas missing values are not empty values, only if save DataFrame with missing values then are replaced by empty strings.

Btw, main problem is mixed values - numeric with strings (empty values), best is convert all strings to numeric for avoid it.

---

You can replace empty values by missing values by `rename`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=[1,2,3,4]), index=[1,2,3,''])
df.index.name = 'i'
df = df.rename({'':np.nan})

df = df.sort_values('i')
print (df)
     x
i     
1.0  1
2.0  2
3.0  3
NaN  4
```

Possible solution if cannot be changed original data is get positions of sorted values by [`Index.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.argsort.html) and change order by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = df.iloc[df.rename({'':np.nan}).index.argsort()]
print (df)
   x
i   
1  1
2  2
3  3
   4
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. In fact, the data comes into the system with missing values and interpreted as `nan`. But, they are converted to empty strings just after reading to help the `groupby` to work as expected. I am having to use empty strings to get `groupby` work, and `nan` to get things like `sort_values` to work. I wish we had another constant like `nan` that does these two.

Comment: @Suresh - I understand now, unfortunately we have to wait for new version of pandas working with missing values in groupby.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But, this comment from the doc sounds like there is no plan to change this behavior of groupby. 

"NA and NaT group handling
If there are any NaN or NaT values in the grouping key, these will be automatically excluded. In other words, there will never be an “NA group” or “NaT group”. This was not the case in older versions of pandas, but users were generally discarding the NA group anyway (and supporting it was an implementation headache)."